# Missing screw holes in Seagate 8 TB hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building, case

The screw holes on 8 TB Seagate hard drives look like this (upper half. The lower half is a “normal” hard drive):

[image: Screw holes on Seagate 8 TB hard drive]

The hard drive trays of my case only provide holes for the front and middle screw holes at the bottom, the holes for the rear screw holes at the bottom are missing. It seems not to be possible to not use the tray and use the side screw holes.

The case is a Xigmatek Midgard. Any other current hardware fits into it without problems. The hard drive cage looks like this:

[image: Xigmatek Midgard hard drive cage]

What are my options to install this drive safely into the Xigmatek Midgard? It is not firmly fixed by just using the two front screw holes.

Comment: I can't tell from the picture for sure, but usually there are holes in the bottom that permit you to place a screw up into the bottom of the drive.

Comment: The mount points on most, but not all, 8TB drives have changed. I can see no valid rationale but that's the case.  I'd vote with my wallet & trade it for one with a regular mount.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've already bought the drive, and don't the WD drives have this issue too?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz As I wrote in the text, the problem is that the middle screw holes at the bottom are missing, too. The drive is installed by screwing it on the tray by using the front and middle screw holes at the bottom and then tray is pushed into the hard drive cage. This is not possible.

Comment: You either need a new drive, a new tray, or put up with 2 attachment points. There is no 4th option.. & I certainly wouldn't suggest drilling it yourself.

Comment: @Tetsujin: is it even possible to buy such trays?

Comment: I can get them for my machine, idk about any universal type, sorry - https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/MPRODBKTLG6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have stumbled across this question when I was looking for a solution for the same problem with my NAS, namely Synology DS211j.

This problem is not new at all. High capacity HDDs now have [relocated the mounting holes](http://www.storagereview.com/6tb_hdds_causing_problems_for_system_vendors_but_not_the_way_you_think) so that they can fit in an extra platter, this [has been happening](http://www.computer-answers.ca/2017/computer-questions/windows-questions/where-did-the-screw-holes-go-8-and-10-tb-hard-drive-mounting-issue/) for the last couple of years. This is probably one reason why many vendors claim that their devices only support HDDs up to 4Tb.

Initially, I just put HDDs on two screws, and the NAS (which is much more lightweight than an average desktop/sever case) made some very unpleasant noises.

Finally, I ended up with just using the two screws plus some not-very-high-tec **pieces of plain paper that add extra tension**. My lovely NAS is now silent, despite the 7200 RPM drives.

[image]

In addition, I've added yet another piece of rolled paper below the lower HDD as it hit the bottom of the case.

[image]

As I said, this is not a high-techie solution at all, but it worked like a charm for me.
**Total cost = $0.00.**

Comment: Thanks. A very nice answer. I bought a new case in the meantime (the Xigmatek Midgard is a very old case), so it's not an issue for me anymore (though you have to be careful: shockingly some newer cases *STILL* don't have been adapted and lack the needed screw holes).

Answer (score 0):

To mount this drive in many cases an adapter is needed. While 2 screws can work, the vibrations could cause issues. The BYTECC BRACKET-2535 will allow you to mount the drive internaly in a 5.25 bay. This is the only one i found when i was looking for a mounting solution for my own Seagate 8T drive and this one does work.